Error: Cannot find module "PROJECT_FOLDER\node_modules\hasura-cli\dist\index.js"
I kept getting this error when I tried to run yarn add hasura-cli -D:
Output:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'PROJECT_FOLDER\node_modules\hasura-cli\dist\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.12.0

As I use NVM for managing node versions, I've tried both node 18 and 20. I've also tried to install hasura-cli globally, but received the same error.

I don't find why that happened, so just install hasura-cli as .exe file in that project.

I've also just run into this, using WSL2 on Windows.

Looks like the maintainers of the package have a build error which means the dist folder is not being placed into the NPM package.
The solution is to roll back to a version that has been built correctly, 2.36.1 for example:
npm install hasura-cli@2.36.1.

You can follow along on the GitHub issue tracking this here: https://github.com/jjangga0214/hasura-cli/issues/116
